# How can I prevent a faucet retaining nut from freezing to a steel washer?

Tags: plumbing, faucet

My real question, after several hours spent removing the old faucet (progressing from tapping the basin wrench with a mallet, to an overnight soak in penetrating oil, to cutting it off with an air grinder) is "what idiot engineer uses a mild steel washer in a wet environment?" But it looks like they all do, or at least the ones who designed the new faucet do, so ...

On the assumption that I or someone else will someday want to change the faucet, what can I use to prevent the nut from freezing to either the washer or the faucet body? If I were working on a car, I'd use thread sealing compound. Does that make sense in this application? Or are there any professional tricks that aren't quite as messy?

Answer (score 3):

[Anti-Seize Lubricating Compound](http://www.allbatterysalesandservice.com/browse.cfm/4,314.html)

Make sure it's waterproof

[image]

[Pipe Dope](http://catalog.antiseize.com/Asset/td25100.pdf)

Make sure it's Anti-seize

[image]

*I do not specifically recommend nor endorse either product, they are only used as examples.*

Comment: I worried this would be the answer. +1, but I'm still hoping that someone else will come up with something less messy in the next couple of hours :-)

Comment: @kdgregory Messy?  I think you're using it wrong.